# React Native Android: How/what is is adding the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission to merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest

I have a React Native Android app that is requesting the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` inside `android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml`, as well as several other places like, `android/app/build/intermediates/bundle_manifest/release/bundle-manifest/AndroidManifest.xml`

This permission is not requested/added to my `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.
I need to find out why this permission is required.

Since it is not present in my `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, I am assuming that is a permission required by one of the packages installed in my app.

How can I go about finding what package/dependency is requiring this permission?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see what packages are requesting what permissions in the manifest-merger-release-report.txt

In my case this was located inside:

```
android/app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-release-report.txt
```